# How to find the generators of the multiplicative group of a finite field

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

**Input**: p (prime number), n (positive number)
**Output**: g ( generator )

I have just found an irreducible polynomial over $F_p[x]$.

Now I must find all generators of the multiplicative group from this irreducible polynomial, but I don't know how to do it.

I'm a newbie so I want to understand clearly how to code this problem.

Anyone have a general solution for this? Please help me step by step.

Comment: There is no tidy solution, like a "Euclidean algorithm" that systematically spits out a generator of a finite field by some universal process.  Just do a web search on phrases like "find a generator finite field" or "find primitive root finite field".  This is an example of a theorem (existence of primitive root) for which it's important to appreciate the proof is fundamentally not constructive.  You can also throw in the word "program" or "code" and find discussions of how to code a search for generators.  This question has been asked many times before.

Comment: It's not even straightforward over $\Bbb F_p$ itself; this is finding a *primitive root* modulo a prime.